# Why does this not work? - Writing data to plist

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am using the following code to modify a plist but to no avail:

```
-(IBAction)modifyPlist:(id)sender{
NSBundle *mainBundle=[NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *path=[mainBundle pathForResource:@"Preferences" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
[dict setValue:@"YES" forKey:@"test"];
[dict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}
```

Does anyone know why it does't change the plist value 'test' from NO to YES?

Answer (score 1):

Long-story-short: because you cannot write into the app bundle.

Comment: You need to write in your Documents folder instead.

Comment: @Cyrille *I* do, or the OP does?

Comment: @trojanfoe you, my dear SO master I've already seen anywhere, are allowed to write anywhere :)

Answer (score 0):

You are writing to your app's bundle directory.  It's ok to read from a plist in that directory, but you aren't allowed to write to your own app's resources so that won't work. Instead you have to write to a plist in the Documents directory, which you can get the path to in a similar way:

```
// Find the path to the plist in the Documents directory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Preferences.plist"];
```